# How to send hyperlink in message body using php mail?

Tags: php, phpmailer

code:

```
$to = "salman.saifi4@gmail.com";
$subject = $subjects;
$txt = "Name:\t".strip_tags($name)."\n\n"."Subject:\t".strip_tags($subject)."\n\n"."Leave Date:\t".$leave_date."\n\n"."Reason:\t".strip_tags($reason)."\n\n".strip_tags("<a href='http://example.com/confirm.php'>Click Here If Leave Application Approve</a>")."\n\n".strip_tags("<a href='http://example.com/not-confirm.php'>Click Here If Leave Application Not Approve</a>");
$headers = "Leave Application";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
```

I am using simple mail function in php and I want to sent a link as I show in my $txt variable when I send email my link look like as I show below:

```
<a href='http://example.com/confirm.php'>click here if leave application approve</a>
<a href='http://example.com/not-confirm.php'>click here if leave application not approve</a>
```

But I want only the text inside the a href tag i.e. (click here if leave application approve) and (click here if leave application not approve) and when I click on the text it redirect me on the link as I have mention. So, How can I do this ?Please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following in headers :

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

And also, for Text:

```
$text = '<html><body>';
$text.= '<a href="http://example.com/confirm.php">click here if leave application approve</a>';
$text.= '<a href="http://example.com/not-confirm.php">click here if leave application not approve</a>';
$text.= '</body></html>';
```

Comment: I am these two line but same issue @Sambhaji Katrajkar

Comment: which issue you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can send html in mail. you can set your message in $message variable

```
$to = "salman.saifi4@gmail.com";
$subject = $subjects;
$message = "<a href='http://example.com/confirm.php'>click here if leave application approve</a>
<a href='http://example.com/not-confirm.php'>click here if leave application not approve</a>";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```